# Nginx not seeing React index.html

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to figure out this nginx 404 error:

> open() "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory)

I am using docker and docker-compose with an nginx image:

```
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

The nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
upstream backend {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name digibrain.co
                www.digibrain.co;

    location / {
        root "/var/www/frontend";
    }    

        location ~ \.(html|css|js)(.*)$ {
    expires -1;
    add_header Cache-Control no-store;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
    
    location /static/ {
        # In dev we need to proxy_pass to the backend.
        # In prod we don't.
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        
        alias /backend/static/;
    }
}
```

The backend works when I go to `localhost/api/` but the frontend broke somehow. thoughts?

Comment: Make sure that in your Nginx config (for `server backend:8000`) you're using the right `backend` **service** name (the name that is used in `docker-compose` file).

Comment: The backend works fine. It is the frontend which is broken. `root "/var/www/frontend";`

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is this part of the code:

```
location ~ \.(html|css|js)(.*)$ {
    expires -1;
    add_header Cache-Control no-store;
}
```

I made a close-enough config file, so to get the same error, and found out you need to define `root` inside this `location`

```
location ~ \.(html|css|js)(.*)$ {
    expires -1;
    add_header Cache-Control no-store;
    root "/var/www/frontend";
}
```

this will enable you to serve frontend from your set folder, but there is a gotcha you need to be aware of:

- if you try to serve any file with this `*.(html|css|js)(.*)` signature from your backend, they will be assumed they are in set frontend folder and thus will give an error (unless have a duplicate name in frontend)

you can find my playground [here](https://github.com/yilmazdurmaz/nginx.conf.docker.example)

---

PS: I have deleted my other post as I assumed a wrong perspective